# Merge virtually two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

Is there a way to merge two tables in MySQL virtually so I could query and insert data?
(which is basicly splitted)

exp.

table

- id
- active
- foo

table_meta

- table_id
- language
- text

What I'd like to do is using something like this instead of sql-join

```
INSERT INTO table_join SET active = 1, language = 'en';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on mySQL 5.1.x, here is a [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html) on what is allowed with regards to an insertable or updatable view.